# Why Does Checkers in Google Precondition Library take object in stead of a String

Tags: java, gwt, guava, preconditions

Why does check* methods in Google Precondition library take an Object instead of a String? I can see that the object is called String.valueOf() on. I think this design was due to not making any assumption on behalf of the client. But I cannot think about a reasonable case where client will be calling this with anything other than a String.

I guess clients could pass an object that has implemented a toString() method. But can you give a real world example on how this can be used/ you have been using this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does check* methods in Google Precondition library take an Object instead of a String?

Performance. If I have an object that is not already a `String`, particularly one where `toString()` is an expensive method, then:

```
checkArgument(valid, obj.toString());
```

will unconditionally call `toString()` and immediately discard the result. On the other hand:

```
checkArgument(valid, obj);
```

can defer that invocation. Since the check is expected to succeed, that deferral avoids waste.

This is the same reason for using log formatting instead of passing a concatenated string ([Logger slf4j advantages of formatting with {} instead of string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555409/logger-sl4fj-advantages-of-formatting-with-instead-of-string-concatenation)).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Joe and plus: null handling.

See the method signature: `checkArgument(boolean expression, @Nullable Object errorMessage)`