# log4j regular expression? [{}]

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Hi I have a question regarding a log4j logger.

There is a part of the logger text I don't quite follow.
The line looks as follows

```
logger.debug("Some text goes here [{}] and some more text here", someObject.function());
```

I had a look but I can't seem to find this as a regular expression, it smells strongly like it could be though and I suspect that it will be replaced by the returned value of `someObject.function()` much how one could replace string values in output by placing a %s. Would I be correct in this assumption? if not please elaborate as to what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a regular expression. `{}` is a special syntax to print out objects and which is preferable over string concatenation. For example,

```
logger.debug("{}, {}", o1, o2); // 2 objects will be printed
logger.debug(o1 + ", " + o2); // the same in concatenation style
```

I suggest reading about [advantages of formatting with `{}` instead of string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555409/logger-sl4fj-advantages-of-formatting-with-instead-of-string-concatenation).

I would like to add that most of the logging systems support [asynchronous logging parameterized messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html), it means you will always get an actual value (it doesn't guarantee by concatenation).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of someObject.function() will get replaced in {}