# Why we use ::{} in java logger

Tags: java, logging

I saw in code some programmer write this in code while log something.

I tried to google why we use ::{} in logger i did not find.
Can some share 
1-why we use it
2- where should use and where should not.

Comment: please provide the entire example usage

Comment: can you please show the full line so one can have the context before answering ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555409/logger-slf4j-advantages-of-formatting-with-instead-of-string-concatenation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logger slf4j advantages of formatting with {} instead of string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555409/logger-slf4j-advantages-of-formatting-with-instead-of-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are referring to message formatter. So the `{}` are like placeholder. In Java there is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html for formatting. So the idea behind is that it allows you to format a string without using messy string concatenation. Assuming there was no such way then you would have to do

```
"I have" + variable1 + " and " + variable2
```

but now instead you can do

```
"I have {0} and {1} and also {0}", variable1, variable2
```

Notice that I can even reuse the same placeholder multiple times. In addition you can do Number, Date Formatting etc.

Hope that helps