# String concatenation performance in Log4j

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j

I have often heard people saying that its one of the best practices to avoid `String Concatenation` and use `{}` instead while logging.

I was looking into the `Log4j` code to see how they have handled this and figured that they are doing something similar.

Here is a snippet of `format()` method which takes the pattern and arguments and returns the message to be logged.

```
/**
 * Formats arguments using SLF4J-like formatter.
 * @param pattern pattern, may be malformed.
 * @param arguments arguments.
 * @return Message string
 */
private static String format(final String pattern,
                             final Object[] arguments) {
    if (pattern != null) {
        String retval = "";
        int count = 0;
        int prev = 0;
        int pos = pattern.indexOf("{");
        while(pos >= 0) {
            if (pos == 0 || pattern.charAt(pos-1) != '\\') {
                retval += pattern.substring(prev, pos);
                if (pos + 1 < pattern.length() && pattern.charAt(pos+1) == '}') {
                    if(arguments != null && count < arguments.length) {
                        retval += arguments[count++];
                    } else {
                        retval += "{}";
                    }
                    prev = pos + 2;
                } else {
                    retval += "{";
                    prev = pos + 1;
                }
            } else {
                retval += pattern.substring(prev, pos - 1) + "{";
                prev = pos + 1;
            }
            pos = pattern.indexOf("{", prev);
        }
        return retval + pattern.substring(prev);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm not able to understand how this implementation is better than using concatenation. Any insights into this will be really helpful.

Comment: What happens if you have a super long string that you need to split up with "+" for readability. But you still keep the "{}" placeholders.
`logger.debug("Very very very very very very very very very very very very very" +
" very very very very long {}", textName);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The benefit of format strings in logging systems is, that the logging system can decide if the string concatenation must happen or not.

Let's use these lines as example:

```
log.debug("Count: " + list.size());
log.debug("Count: {}", list.size());
```

As long as the level for this logger is debug or below, there is no difference in performance, but if the log level is higher than debug the second line won't perform the concatenation at all.

Comment: What happens if you have a super long string that you need to split up with "+" for readability. But you still keep the "{}" placeholders.
`logger.debug("Very very very very very very very very very very very very very" +
" very very very very long {}", textName);`

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer That's not a problem, This constant string concatenation will be performed ahead of time by the compiler.

Comment: So only concatenation between method calls and strings matters?

Comment: Concatenations between String literals and/or String constants are fine, as they can be performed ahead of time by the compiler. It gets "bad" when non-constant expressions like method calls, local variables, or non-static fields are involved, where the concatenation has to be performed at runtime.

Comment: Would there be performance difference if I use a StringBuilder vs this String formatting?

Answer (score 8):

Some of the answers to this question explain:

- [Logger slf4j advantages of formatting with {} instead of string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555409)

The short version is that format-based usage faster because in

```
   Logger.debug("my name is {}", name);
```

the expensive string bashing only occurs *after* log4j decides that the event needs to be logged; e.g. after the filtering based on the logging level, etcetera.

By contrast, with the string concatenation version

```
   Logger.debug("my name is " + name);
```

the string bashing happens while evaluating the arguments.  Thus, it happens even in the cases where no event is actually logged.  You can partially avoid that by adding "guards" in your code (see below), but doing that makes your applications logging calls verbose.

---

But take a look at this example:

```
   log.debug("Count: " + list.size());
   log.debug("Count: {}", list.size());
```

The format version will be faster, but both versions *always* evaluate the `list.size()` expression.  If that is an expensive operation, then you may need to resort to using a guard; e.g.

```
   if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
       log.debug("Count: " + list.size());
   }
```

Comment: So there won't be any performance benefits if that particular logging level (`debug` in this case) is enabled?

Comment: Correct.  But people generally don't run code in production with debug level logging.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to not execute list.size() :

```
// Instead of
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   log.debug("Count: " + list.size());
}

// Use if >= Java 8
log.debug("Count: {}", () -> list.size());
```

This will evaluate list.size() only when needed.

Credit : https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-log4j-api-and-lambda-basics/