# should I be using slf4j isTraceEnabled or not?

Tags: java, scala, slf4j

If I print lot of data in case trace is enabled should i be using `isTraceEnabled` or just do my `log.trace("{} mymessage", "param")`
would there be any benefit in this case to using `isTraceEnabled` or no benefit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends what `"param"` actually is. If it is a complex expression it is better to use `isTraceEnabled`. If it is just a reference to an object you can use it directly. Its `toString` method will only be called if tracing is enabled.

Using `isTraceEnabled` is also beneficial if you have several trace statements in a row. You can can put them into the same `if` then.

Answer (score 3):

While Henry's answer is correct, I wanted to add that `trace` will effectively have to call `isTraceEnabled` anyway, so there is actually a (very small) drawback to calling `isTraceEnabled` when it *isn't* useful (i.e. you don't need to construct the parameters by non-trivial expressions and you only have a single `trace` call).